# Is the reanimated Minato much stronger than when he was alive?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto chapter 618, all the souls that are bound inside the shinigami of the shiki fuujin were pulled out by Orochimaru. It includes the souls of the four previous Hokages. Now, before his death, Minato was able to seal half of the nine tails chakra into his own. Does it mean that he is much stronger than he when was alive? Does he have any chance on using the kyuubi's chakra for himself just like what Naruto did?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The resurrected Minato *is* stronger than when he was alive, but that is due to the properties of Edo Tensei (unlimited chakra, near-unlimited stamina, and automatic regeneration of any damage taken).

<s>Minato does not have Kurama's chakra inside him. The Yin-component of Kurama's chakra, sealed by Minato, is still inside the Shinigami's stomach. Shiki Fuujin does not seal the target's soul into the summoner's soul. They are both sealed together, but independently, in the Shinigami's stomach.</s>

This can be confirmed since Orochimaru first recovered the soul of his arms and then the four previous Kage at once. If the Shiki Fuujin sealed the target's soul into the summoner's soul, he would have to first recover Hiruzen's soul, and then the souls of Hashirama, Tobirama and his arms from Hiruzen's soul.

Minato *does* seem to have Kurama's Yin part inside of him. As proven by the recent chapters. Which undoubtedly proves that he's much stronger compared to the way he was before his death.

**Note**: This answer is based on events seen till Chapter 623. The answer may become obsolete after subsequent chapters.

Comment: So that means that Yin-Kurama is now released somewhere? The Shiki seal was broken, after all.

Comment: It's not clear yet (to me, at least), but my pure speculation is that Kurama has a Yin-soul and a Yang-soul. Kurama's Yang-soul was sealed within Naruto (along with the Yang-chakra), while the Yin-soul and Yin-chakra is still in the Shinigami's stomach. With the Shiki Fuujin seal broken, it can be summoned using Edo Tensei.

Comment: Further, my guess is that once the focus shifts back to Madara's battle, he will realise that Kurama's Yin-chakra is missing within Naruto, and so summon Yin-Kurama with Edo Tensei. Unlike Obito, Madara wants to revive the Juubi perfectly, so he will need the Kyuubi's full chakra.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha do you really agree with resurrected Minato is stronger than when he was alive, but that is due to the properties of Edo Tensei (unlimited chakra, near-unlimited stamina, and automatic regeneration of any damage taken)? Then why did you used obito to bring you back to alive? Why was third hokage was able to defeat the first and second without much trouble?

Answer (score 1):

No. The Shiki Fuujin seals the souls. That means that the chakra of the Kyuubi is sealed independently from the soul of Minato. If you revive a soul, you only revive the own soul, but not anything that was sealed inside his *body*.

Comment: what about the chakra of the kyuubi? where is it?

Comment: @janbert: Maybe it's back to the kyuubi. It isn't clear, maybe it'll be clear in later chapters.

Comment: Kurama's chakra has not been explicitly taken out and so is still inside the Shinigami's stomach, IMHO.